# How to check if a string begins with prefix and contains specific keyword in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to find an efficient way of doing this.  A function to return True if the entry  string has a Ph.D/Medical Doctor ( which means prefix  of 'Dr.') and the entry has name 'Alex' in it.

I tried the below code which works, but I think there should be a more efficient way of doing it. I will appreciate any thoughts.

```
str1 = "Dr. Moses Alex"
str2 = "Dr. Ben Mora"

def match st
  if st.include?('Dr.') and st.include?('Alex')
    return true
  else 
   return false
 end
end
```

match(str1) # true
match(str2) # false

Comment: What in this code is checking for `Dr.` at the beginning (as opposed to anywhere in the string)?  `match("Alex not a Dr.")` yields `true`.

Comment: I see your point. I think it's related to one of the other suggestion I got regarding using another function to handle the prefix.

Comment: Watch out for strings such as "Dr. Alexa P. Isamoron".

Comment: I feel like this question could use a bit more clarification since you mentioned a prefix of "Dr." and you also mention both "Ph.D" and "Medical Doctor" which are commonly used as a suffix such as in "Alexis Smith, M.D." or "Jonathan Alexander, Ph.D".  In addition, it should be clarified whether you're looking for the first name or the last name, and how the names are being entered, imported, or otherwise formatted before you try running your match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good. The only feedback I have is regarding the use of 'include?' function for the prefix. Try to use 'start_with?' function instead, so that you don't get True even when the the "Dr" is within the string.

```
def match st
  if st.start_with?('Dr.') and st.include?('Alex')  
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: `st.start_with?('Dr.') and st.include?('Alex')` returns `true` or `false`, so the `if` clause serves no purpose. Also, if `st = "Dr. Alexi Dodo"` the expression returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) with a simple regular expression:

```
r = /\ADr\..+\bAlex\b/
```

```
"Dr. J. Alex Knowitall".match?(r) #=> true
"He's Dr. J. Alex Knowitall".match?(r) #=> false
"Dr. J. Alexander Knowitall".match?(r) #=> false
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
r =
/
\A    # match beginning of string
Dr\.  # match literal "Dr."
.+    # match one or more characters, as many as
      # possible, other than line terminators
\b    # match a word boundary
Alex  # match literal "Alex"
\b    # match a word boundary
/x    # assert free-spacing regex definition mode
```

With any solution some strings, if permitted, may cause problems, an example being, "Dr. Bubba Knowitall and Alex are brothers".

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified to:

```
def match(string)
  string.start_with?('Dr.') && string.include?('Alex')  
end
```

This works because a method in Ruby always implicitly returns the value returned by the last statement. Therefore there is no need for explicit returns.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks